# Why isn't my program removing "all"?

Tags: java, arraylist

My problem is, when I output this code, it's not outputting what I want which is to remove the "all". It outputs the same exact thing the first print statement did.

Here's my code:

```
// RemoveAll
// Spec: To remove the "all"
// ArrayList remove() exercise

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RemoveAll
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<String> ray;
    ray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int spot = ray.size() - 1;

    ray.add("all");
    ray.add("all");
    ray.add("fun");
    ray.add("dog");
    ray.add("bat");
    ray.add("cat");
    ray.add("all");
    ray.add("dog");
    ray.add("all");
    ray.add("all");
    System.out.println(ray);
    System.out.println(ray.size());

    // add in a loop to remove all occurrences of all
    while (spot >= 0)
    {
        if (ray.get(spot).equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
        {
            ray.remove(spot);
        }

        spot = spot - 1;
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + ray);
    System.out.println(ray.size());
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are determining `size()` before filling list

put this after once you have list filled (i.e. after all `add()`)

```
int spot = ray.size() - 1;
```

Comment: Yep, you're setting the value of "spot" to array size, then adding to it, then using spot without resetting it. Also, you're mutating the array with remove() while you're iterating over it, which is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to remove items from the list is to use an `Iterator`:

```
for(Iterator<String> i = ray.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    if(i.next().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
       i.remove();
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to keep track of where you are in the list with respect to removed items.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. You are setting the size of spot before the array has any values in it so it will have a value of -1 when you get to
`while (spot >= 0)`

also you are mutating (modifying) the array while you are iterating over it which will cause all sorts of errors. The way you want to do this is using an iterator

```
Iterator iter = ray.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
String cur = iter.next();
//logic to determin if you need to remove
iter.remove();

}
```